# Double arrows in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

How do I add another arrow (like one on the right, current i(t)) also on the left side of the component? To get something like:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Circuitikz is a tikzpicture, ao adding an arrow and node is easy.  Matching the one produced by circuitikz might be harder.  Although as a "through" vairable, what is the point?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea could be using `short` to support the arrows:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[short, o-, i=$i(t)$] ++(0.5,0)
        to[generic] ++(1.5,0)
        to[short, -o, i=$i(t)$] ++(0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can fine-tune (although somehow visually) the arrows:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \tikzset{ipos/.style={/tikz/circuitikz/current/distance=#1}}
    \draw (0,0) to[short, o-, i=$i(t)$, ipos=0.8] ++(0.5,0)
        to[generic] ++(1.5,0)
        to[short, -o, i=$i(t)$, ipos=0.2] ++(0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]